# alternative to the_content filter

Tags: filters, actions, the-content

"i am using the_content filter on the category pages like cat=1" I am appending --N in the content. But due the the theme functionality it strip the content after some number of characters therefore in post with the less content i can see the "--N" string but with the large content i cant see "--N" string as the "content" is being stripped. I want to append the '--N' string every time.
Is there is any other way to append the content?
[image]

Code

```
function rate_post_content($content) {
    if(is_category()){
        global $post;
        return $content."---N"; // here any test can come
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'rate_post_content');
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you want to achieve. Could you maybe reword your question?

Comment: @intekhabkhan Please post the code you are currently using to do what you are doing i.e. to append the "--N" string.

Comment: Done i have added code.I am using this code in plugin

Comment: Is the Theme actually *calling* `the_content()`? It appears that it is calling `the_excerpt()` in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**In functions.php:**

```
function myExcerpt($text) {
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $excerpt_length = 50; // max number of words
    $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);

    array_pop($words);
    array_push($words, '-N');
    $text = implode(' ', $words);
    return $text;
}
```

**In your loops**:

```
echo myExcerpt ( get_the_content() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say run your filter in a later priority, say 50 or so:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'rate_post_content', 50 );
```

Same goes for the excerpt filter. You just need to make sure the excerpt process is done before your filter is applied.